# Do I need a wire connected to the negative terminal for led light bars and if so can I use the negative terminal as ground for the relay

Tags: led, ground, light

I'm not sure if this will work can someone help me out

[image: This is a diagram I drew of my setup can someone tell me if it will work or not. Thank you!]

Comment: The relay pin numbers are special to automotive electrics. We use symbols for the relay coil and contact. If you edit your question to include the relay pin functions you should get some help.

Comment: There's a schematic editor on this site; press the edit button on your question and click the icon of a schematic with a pencil. What are the terminals of your relay here?

Comment: That diagram could use some work

Answer (score 1):

You do need connections between the negative (grounded) terminals of the lights and the negative terminal of the battery.

If these lights are on a vehicle, the metal frame and body of the vehicle can serve as the negative/ground connection, as the negative terminal of the vehicle battery will be connected to the vehicle frame.

Answer (score 1):

The negative connections for light bars should be returned to the factory chassis ground, this is where the negative battery cable is bolted to the chassis. You should not rely on the vehicle frame to be a good ground return.
Installation manuals are available for most lightbars on the manufacturer's website, they should have detailed instructions.